# Django (DRF) Boolean Field missing in JSON

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm writing a rather simple REST API using Django REST Framework. I am trying to add a boolean field to my model that would show if it is publicly accessible or not.

In my models.py, my model looks like this:

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='', blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=140, default='', blank=False)
    is_public   = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=False)
```

Then in my serializers.py, my serializer for the model looks like this:

```
class BlogPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ('title', 'description', 'is_public')
```

However, when I create an instance of that model, and run my development server, the JSON **only returns the title and the description**. The `is_public` field **is missing** from the JSON.

I've searched everywhere and can't find the reason for this odd problem.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the result of `BlogPost.objects.all()`?

Comment: Ok, shame on me. This was a new field and apparently I made the editions on an obsolete serializer, that was not used in any views, that's why it didn't show up. What a silly mistake, I spent several hours on it yesterday!

Comment: @NikitaAlexander Are you me? I had the same stupid problem, and the same stupid solution, it even involves a boolean variable `is_public`.